# jQuery Auto Scroll to DIV ID

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

I have a div id a third of the way down a web page

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollHere"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var elem = $('#scrollHere');
if(elem) {
    $(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top).scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
}

/*
var destination = $('#scrollHere').offset().top;
    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-75}, 800 );
    return false;
*/
/*
var elem = $('#scrollHere');
if(elem) {

$(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top).scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
    //$('html').scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
    //$('html').scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
}
*/


/*
    var elem = $('#scrollHere');
    if(elem) {
        //$.scrollTo(elem.left, elem.top);
        //$(document).stop().scrollTo( elem.offset().left, elem.offset().top );
    }
*/

}); // end .ready()
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
#scrollHere{
    position:relative;
    top:500px;
    left:1000px;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

But I can't get autoscroll to take me to the div id on page refresh.

Am I using the wrong JavaScript commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a `scrollTo`-Function in jQuery? I thought you need a plugin for that.
However, this works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/5VQCD/

```
var elem = $('#scrollHere');
if(elem) {
    $('html').scrollTop(elem.offset().top);
    $('html').scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
}
```

Comment: Loked at your jsFiddle @Alex. I did not have any css so I added some using yours as a template. My page did not auto scroll.

Comment: strange, if I paste your code in my fiddle it works.
do you include the jQuery correctly? can you show us your page somehow? URL?

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I use google api lib v1.7.1 for jquery. I wish I could show you the page but it sits behind a private firewall within our enterprise. I need to cut this glitzy feature loose and move on. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to achieving this by changing the scrollTop and scrollLeft of the DOM window.

```
$(window).scrollTop(elem.offset().top).scrollLeft(elem.offset().left);
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/5VQCD/1/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to add a little something to my web page. But I spending way too much time trying to get it to work. Thanks for helping...

Comment: Agreed @Starx. I've done that religiously to each of the 100 questions I have asked on the various S.O. sites where I have a workable/usable answer. But with this particular question, I have no way of knowing which of the answers works.

Comment: @DrDOT, I made a demo with a working solution, that's all i can do to help.